# Individually assigning page links to buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replicate the code below to open up a different page, each time. Please see:

[image: Page example]

Code:

```
        
        <section class="container g-py-15">
        <div class="g-brd-around g-brd-5 g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-pa-30">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9 align-self-center">
                <h3 class="h4">Task 1 &amp; Extension</h3>
                  <p class="lead g-mb-20 g-mb-0--md">Set up the inital track markers</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 align-self-center text-md-right">
                    
                    
                    <button onclick="openWin()">Open code</button>
                    
                    <button onclick="closeWin()">Close code</button>
                    <script>
                            let myWindow;

                            function openWin() {
                              myWindow = window.open("8_1python/task1.html", "_blank", "width=800, height=800");
                            }

                            function closeWin() {
                              myWindow.close();
                            }
                            
                    </script>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
        
        <section class="container g-py-15">
        <div class="g-brd-around g-brd-5 g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-pa-30">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9 align-self-center">
                <h3 class="h4">Task 2 &amp; Extension</h3>
                  <p class="lead g-mb-20 g-mb-0--md">Complete the track set up&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 align-self-center text-md-right">
                    
                                        
                    <button onclick="openWin()">Open code</button>
                    
                    
                    <button onclick="closeWin()">Close code</button>
                    <script>
                            let myWindow;

                            function openWin() {
                              myWindow = window.open("8_1python/task2.html", "_blank", "width=800, height=800");
                            }

                            function closeWin() {
                              myWindow.close();
                            }
                            
                    </script>
```

This works fine to open up task 1, but when I want to replicate the code for task 2, it still opens up task 1.

It opens up task 1 each time. Above I have posted the repeated code for task 1, which works fine, and task 2 which does not.

Comment: How many functions called `openWin()` do you have after replicating the code for task 2?

Comment: Hi, there are 4 tasks on the page, and the above code is repeated each time for each task.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you attempted to call `task2.html`. Makes it hard to tell what the problem is. @Playacar Don't  try to explain your changes, improve the answer to show the actual code you're using and how it's not working.

Comment: @playacar Why would you rollback the changes I made? Just curious

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're using inline handlers in 2024...

Comment: If you repeat the code, you're redefining the functions. All the buttons call the last one.

Comment: Instead of repeating the function definitions, use functions with parameters and return values. Then put the parameters in the `onclick`.

Comment: @Barmar, they still need to create more references to the opened window object so they can be closed

Comment: @RuanMendes Yes, that's the return value: `win1 = openWin('URL')`

Comment: Hi @Barmar, can you recommend a fix please?

Answer (score 3):

Use a single pair of functions with parameters and return values.

```
<button onclick="win1 = openWin('python/task1.html')">Open code</button>

<button onclick="closeWin(win1)">Close code</button>

<button onclick="win2 = openWin('python/task2.html')">Open code</button>

<button onclick="closeWin(win2)">Close code</button>

<script>
function openWin(url) {
    return window.open(url, "_blank", "width=800, height=800");
}

function closeWin(win) {
    win.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can delete `myWindow`. Kind of stinks not to teach them a better way than creating globals through inline handers.

Comment: Yeah, but a "good" solution would be fairly complicated, since it needs an object to hold the window for each close button to close. @RuanMendes

Comment: I tried to come up with [a better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77996047/227299) that is not too complicated.

Comment: That solution is pretty much what I was thinking of, I was just too lazy to write it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting you previous definitions of `myWindow`, `openWindow` and `closeWin` if you just copy paste the snippet modifying the URL to open.

I'll show you a way to do it without inline handlers since they are considered dangerous, outdated and disallowed by strict CSP headers.

You can store the `url` to open and a `taskId` as data attributes. Then you can use your event handler to open that URL and to store the reference in a global variable that tracks the open windows.

```
<button data-taskId="task1" data-url="python/task1.html" class="open">Open Task 1</button>

<button data-taskId="task1" class="close">Close code</button>


<button data-taskId="task2" data-url="python/task2.html" class="open">Open Task 2</button>

<button data-taskId="task2" class="close">Close code</button>

<script>

const openWindows = {};

for (const el of document.querySelectorAll("button.open")) {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Close existing windows
    if (openWindows[e.target.dataset.taskId]) {
        openWindows[e.target.dataset.taskId].close();
    }
    openWindows[e.target.dataset.taskId] = window.open(e.target.dataset.url, "_blank", "width=800, height=800");
  });
}

for (const el of document.querySelectorAll("button.close")) {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (openWindows[e.target.dataset.taskId]) {
        openWindows[e.target.dataset.taskId].close();
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons will open the same URL unless you give a different URL.

Here's a simple example of a fixed window opener:

```
<button onclick="openWin('python/task1.html')">Open code</button>

<button onclick="closeWin()">Close code</button>

<script>
let myWindow;

function openWin(url) {
    myWindow = window.open(url, "_blank", "width=800, height=800");
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

There are further improvements to make still. Most glaring issues first.

1. Clicking multiple <kbd>Open code</kbd> buttons will cause break the <kbd>Close code</kbd> buttons. I.e. you'll have an un-closable window.
2. The <kbd>Close code</kbd> button will close *any* active window, not just the one for that example.
3. You can click the <kbd>Open code</kbd> button twice and it'll open multiple windows.

Here's how I solved those issues:

- Index the window object by its URL
- Test if it already exists if

```
<button onclick="openWin('python/task1.html')">Open code</button>

<button onclick="closeWin('python/task1.html')">Close code</button>
<script>
let myWindows = {};

function openWin(url) {
    if (!myWindows[url] || myWindows[url].closed) {
        myWindows[url] = window.open(url, "_blank", "width=800, height=800");
    }
}

function closeWin(url) {
    if (myWindows[url]) {
        myWindows[url].close();
        delete(myWindows[url]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes Ive specified different URLs..

Comment: Bug: Your `closeWin()` will only close the last window that was opened.

Comment: @RuanMendes That's not a bug I introduced. See second code block.

Comment: Not a bug you introduced? It's your suggestion on how to fix the code which didn't fix the code?